# Is the subset 1/2^n compact?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces, compactness

Is the subset 
$$[{\frac{1}{2^{n}}|n\epsilon \mathbb{N}}] \cup [2]$$ compact

My thoughts: Use Heine-Borel which states any closed and bounded subset is compact. The sequence $$(\frac{1}{2^{n}})$$ is bounded and is closed since the sequence $$(\frac{1}{2^{n}})$$ which is a subset of A, converges to 1∈A. So the subset is compact. Is this correct?

(Apologies, as I am not great at the coding on this)

Comment: What does it mean to say that a sequence is closed?

Comment: If X is a metric space and A⊂X, then A is closed in the m.s. iff any sequence in A which converges in X converges in A.

Comment: I think your notation is a little confusing.

Comment: Sorry, could you explain what part you find confusing? (I just realised I missed a point out so I have edited it)

Comment: Is $[2]$ meant to be the singleton set containing the number $2$, usually writeen $\{2\}$? You can write { and } in MathJax using `\{` and `\}`. Using standard set-notation brackets when writing a set would make the question clearer.

Comment: Yes, sorry i couldnt work out how to type that

Answer (score 2):

A subset is closed if and only if all of its limit points belong to the set. It remains to prove that there are indeed no limit points of this set which lie outside of the set (which isn't terribly hard to do).

Boundedness is trivial here, and as you pointed out, closedness and boundedness together imply compactness in $\mathbb{R}$ with the standard topology.

Comment: I think only limit point is $2$ which belongs to the set? Hence set is closed.

Comment: Yes, $2$ is the only limit point - this should be proven though

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, you can use the formal definition of compactness.  If you have an open covering of the set, then some open set covers a neighborhood of $2$ and therefore it must cover all but a finite number of other members of the set.

Comment: Now this is the definition that I'm not very clear on. So for this definition would I try to find an open covering for the set which does not have any finite subcovering? I don't know if that's the correct idea...

Comment: @user722737 You are given any collection of open sets whose union is $S$, and you need to prove that a finite number of members **of that specific collection** also covers $S$.

Comment: @user722737 I know that Heine-Borel seems like a great excuse to not have to understand compactness directly, but it's a trap! ^_^

Comment: Yes that's what I'm thinking!! It feels like a shortcut way to get to the correct answer without understanding the process!!

Answer (score 0):

Define the $k^{\text{th}}$ partial sum

$\tag 1 {\displaystyle s_{k}=\sum _{n=0}^{k} 2^{-n}}$

Define

$\tag 2 L = \{ s_k \mid k \in \Bbb N\} \,\bigcup \,\{2\}$

It is not difficult to show that $L$ is contained in an open ball of radius $2$, so $L$ is bounded.

Define $R_{-1} = (-\infty, 1)$ and $R_{0} = (2, +\infty)$.

For integer $n \ge 1$ define

$\tag 3 U_n = \big(s_{n-1},s_{n}\big)$

The union of this family of open intervals.

$\tag 4 U = \displaystyle{\bigcup_{n \ge -1} U_n}$

is open. So the complement of $U$, call it $K$, must be a closed set.

To show that $L = K$, we'll need the following algebraic identity,

$\tag 5 \text{For every integer } k, \quad 2^{-k} - 2^{-(k+1)}  = 2^{-(k+1)}$

Using $\text{(5)}$ we can show, using induction, that every partial sum $s_k$ satisfies

$\tag 6 s_k = 2 - 2^{-k}$

## $ L \subset K$:

We have $2 \in L$ and using $\text{(6)}$ that $2 \notin U$; therefore $2 \in K$.

Let $x \ne 2$ belong to $L$. Then $x = s_k$ for some $k$. Since $1 \le s_k \le 2$ and the sequnece $s_n$ is increasing, we can write $s_k \notin U$ and also $s_k \in K$.

## $ K \subset L$:

Again, we only have to demonstrate that if $x \in K$ and $x \ne 2$ then $x = s_k$ for some $k$. But since $x \notin U$ we can write $x \in [1,2)$.  Knowing that the real numbers satisfies the [axiom of Archimedes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Archimedean_property#Ordered_fields) we can argue the existence of an integer $k \ge 0$ such that $x \in [s_k,s_{k+1})$. Since $[s_k,s_{k+1}) = U_{k+1} \cup \{s_k\}$ and by assumption $x \notin U$, we must have $x = s_k$.